# which way is a better practice for routing in Play Framework with Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

https://github.com/wsargent/play-jdk13-alpine-slim/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/myservice/AppComponents.scala

https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-scala-starter-example/conf/routes

https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-scala-rest-api-example/conf/routes

I see in Play there are 3 ways to specify routes, as shown above, which way is considered the recommended one? Which folder structure is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code example uses a [SIRD](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaSirdRouter#String-Interpolating-Routing-DSL) router, whereas the second example uses a generated router from a routes file.

The third example just uses a routes file which generates a router that passes control to another router for a specific prefix -- no matter whether this was generated or hand-coded. So, this is no different than the second example.

There is no clear advantage of one over the other. Using a routes files is usually more succinct and "easier", but you have more control when using the DSL to bind your routes to some actions.

The folder structure is also merely a matter of taste; go with the default layout and you should be fine.